# Jersey - cookie set on a client does not arrive to the server

Tags: java, cookies, jersey

I am writing a client application with jersey java libraries, I am not succesfull in sending cookies to the server. Where is my mistake? Here is my code:

CLIENT:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(getUrl());  

    //Create invocation builder
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(getMime_type());

    //Set the cooky

    invocationBuilder = invocationBuilder.cookie("mioCookie","value of my cookie");

    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

SERVER:

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileService {
    Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "file.log";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response getFile(@CookieParam(value = "mioCookie") String mioCookie) {
        LOG.info("***** Cookie in input: " + mioCookie);
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
        NewCookie modifiedCookie = new NewCookie("mioCookie", mioCookie + "- modified");
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=\"file_from_server.log\"");
        response.cookie(modifiedCookie);
        return response.build();

    }
```

what is written by the log is:

```
infos: ***** Cookie in input: null.
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters filter to log incoming requests? Thanks to this you will know if the problem is in the client or server code.

Comment: @Adam That's a good suggestion, this is also achievable using web debugging utilities that inspect internet traffic (e.g. http://fiddler2.com/)

Comment: Just tested your code with Jersey 2.5 (client) and Jersey 1.17 (server). It works : `***** Cookie in input: value of my cookie`

Answer (score 1):

You may simply add `Response response = target.request().cookie(Your Cookie)` while you make the call. Do not call the builder explicitly as it will not add the cookie in your final call. This should get the cookie added to your call. 
An example call for a post is added for more clarity 
`Response response =webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cookie(cookie).buildPost(Entity.entity(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();`
Hope that helps